# Making attribute in json request object not null

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I'm building a Spring application which has `@RestController`, like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/master")
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    @PostMapping("/call")
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> apiCall(@RequestBody MyDTO myDto) { ;
        return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(service.apiCall(myDto), OK);
    }

}
```

And a request object:

```
public class MyDTO {

    @JsonProperty("emp_number")
    private long empNumber;

    @JsonProperty("office_id")
    private long officeId;

    // ....constructors, etc.
}
```

In request json I want `officeId` to be **not null.**

So far I've tried marking the `officeId` field as:

```
@com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@JsonProperty(required = true)
@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
```

But in the request json, even if I miss `office_id`, it is not throwing any error.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you want to use `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` annotation check that Hibernate validatator dependency added. Also try to add @Validated annotation on your class.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that in your case you are deserializing request, and missing primitive properties which are referenced by constructor are assigned a default value

[java defaults](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

You could try to use corresponding Long wrapper object for *MyDTO* instead of primitives or maybe deserialization feature [FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the type from primitive to wrapper otherwise the default value of 0 will be considered and validation will pass.

Annotate MyDTO with `@Valid` annotation.

> When Spring Boot finds an argument annotated with @Valid, it automatically bootstraps the default JSR 380 implementation — Hibernate Validator — and validates the argument.

from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation)

Please add following dependency to pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

*PS: i have made minor adjustments to response structure to see the error in response*

Entire code is as follows:

```java
package com.example.spring.java.springjavasamples;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringJavaSamplesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringJavaSamplesApplication.class, args);
    }

}

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/master")
class MyController {

    private final MyService service;

    public MyController(MyService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @PostMapping("/call")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> apiCall(@Valid @RequestBody MyDTO myDto, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
            bindingResult.getAllErrors().forEach((error) -> {
                String fieldName = ((FieldError) error).getField();
                String errorMessage = error.getDefaultMessage();
                errors.put(fieldName, errorMessage);
            });
            return prepareResponse("error", errors, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } else {
            return prepareResponse("data", service.apiCall(myDto), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }

    private ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> prepareResponse(String key, Object data, HttpStatus status) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(key, data);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(map, status);
    }

}

class MyDTO {

    @NotNull(message = "Employee number cannot be null")
    @JsonProperty("emp_number")
    private Long empNumber;

    @NotNull(message = "Office Id cannot be null")
    @JsonProperty("office_id")
    private Long officeId;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyDTO{" +
                "empNumber=" + empNumber +
                ", officeId=" + officeId +
                '}';
    }
}

@Service
class MyService {

    public String apiCall(MyDTO myDto) {
        System.out.println("all valid: " + myDto);
        return myDto.toString();
    }
}
```